# How to cancel a hangup scheduled with `sched_hangup`?

Tags: freeswitch

The [`sched_hangup`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools%3A+sched+hangup) doc doesn't mention how to do this, and [`sched_cancel`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools%3A+sched+cancel) only works for [`sched_transfer`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools%3A+sched+transfer) and [`sched_broadcast`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools%3A+sched+broadcast).

<sup>[`sched_cancel`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools%3A+sched+cancel) needs a task or group ID, and only the latter two set the ID in the session, I tested.</sup>

Or is there another way to get the task ID?

Answer (score 0):

#### Workaround

Couldn't find a solution, but this workaround effectively solved the problem:

> Set up [`sched_transfer`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools%3A+sched+transfer) to a non-existent extension, which will
>   result in a hangup with `No route, Aborting`, unless aborted with
>   [`sched_cancel`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools%3A+sched+cancel).

Below is a Lua example, but this strategy would work in the dialplan just the same because the `sched_*` commands are all dialplan applications (i.e., part of [`mod_dptools`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools)).

```
session:execute("sched_transfer", "+600 9999 XML default")
-- ...
local lsi = session:getVariable("last_sched_id")
session:execute("sched_cancel", tostring(lsi))
```